# IntelliJ inspection working for Java files, not for Groovy files

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy

When running IntelliJ, inline correction of imports, syntax and other things seem to be "offline" for Groovy scripts. For Java, everything works OK.

JavaClass.java:

```
public class JavaClass {
    private final Instant instant;
}
```

- Expected: Cannot resolve symbol `Instant`. Import class --> Alt-Shift-Enter
- Actual: Cannot resolve symbol `Instant`. Import class --> Alt-Shift-Enter

GroovyClass.groovy:

```
class GroovyClass {
    private final Instant instant
}
```

- Expected: Cannot resolve symbol `Instant`. Import class --> Alt-Shift-Enter
- Actual: Variable 'instant' might not have been initialized

In the Project panel on the left, `JavaClass` is underlined red, but `GroovyClass` is not. Not until the compiler is invoked using `Ctrl-F9` will then the message appear `Groovyc: unable to resolve class Instant`

After upgrading to IJ 2020.2.2 the feature was OK for an hour or so, and then it went "offline" again.

Software in use:

- IntelliJ 2020.2.2
- Java 11 GraalVM CE 20.1.0 (build 11.0.7+10-jvmci-20.1-b02)
- Groovy 3.0.5

We have tried

- Using IntelliJ 2019.3
- Upgrading it to 2020.2.2
- Invalidate Cache + Restart
- Using a Java 8 JDK instead of 11
- Turning Power Save mode on/off

Comment: Is there anything related to Groovy in idea.log (Help | Show log...)? Does it help if you remove .idea folder and reimport the project?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Petr for your suggestion.

What worked for me was downgrading to JDK 8 from version 11, and making sure IntelliJ uses the same JDK that is used by Gradle, so that meant using the IntelliJ without the bundled runtime. After that I could use any IntelliJ I wanted, they all just worked.

As a bonus my long-running process became faster by 18%, and IntellIJ itself too (running on Linux)

- GraalVM 8  20.1.0.r8  134m
- GraalVM 11 20.1.0.r11 159m